# Highly nested json data

Tags: java, json

I have three JSON arrays named item, topping and batter.
Now I want to store this data into single json object. It is highly nested data I don't know how to store data into single object like this.

Resultant object should be like this:

```
{
    "item": [{
            "id": "0001",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Cake",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batter": [{
                    "id": "1001",
                    "type": "Regular"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1002",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1003",
                    "type": "Blueberry"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1004",
                    "type": "Devil's Food"
                }

            ],
            "topping": [{
                    "id": "5001",
                    "type": "None"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5002",
                    "type": "Glazed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5005",
                    "type": "Sugar"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5007",
                    "type": "Powdered Sugar"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5006",
                    "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5003",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5004",
                    "type": "Maple"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Raised",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batter": [{
                "id": "1001",
                "type": "Regular"
            }],

            "topping": [{
                    "id": "5001",
                    "type": "None"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5002",
                    "type": "Glazed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5005",
                    "type": "Sugar"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5003",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5004",
                    "type": "Maple"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0003",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Old Fashioned",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batter": [{
                    "id": "1001",
                    "type": "Regular"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1002",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                }
            ],

            "topping": [{
                    "id": "5001",
                    "type": "None"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5002",
                    "type": "Glazed"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5003",
                    "type": "Chocolate"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5004",
                    "type": "Maple"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your json is correct. please use JSONObject and JSONArray Class to get the each nodes of your data :) Thank you

Comment: could you pls elobrate it with example

Comment: where are you getting the three arrays? whats the format of the input json arrays and whats the logic to map them as the resultant object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json)